# Интересный кейс: как автоматически отправлять правки с сайта в гитхаб?

Tags: javascript, github

Опишу поподробнее, что я имею ввиду. Я хочу задеплоить сайт на GitHub Pages и создать на этом сайте функцию "предложить редактирование". "Предложить редактирование" будет отсылать pull request в соответствующий репозиторий. То есть любой посетитель сайта сможет нажать на кнопку "предложить редактирование", у него откроется окно с редактором текста на странице сайта, затем он сможет внести свои предложения, сохранить и отправить свои изменения как pull request.
Соответственно задача делится на две части:

1. Во-первых, нужно создать режим редактирования текста на сайте.
2. Во-вторых, сделать возможность отправки изменений в качестве пулл реквеста.

Ограничения: Github Pages не дает возможность использовать серверные скрипты, только javascript.

Пожалуйста, расскажите, что вы думаете по поводу поставленных задача. Знаете ли вы способ автоматической отправки пулл реквестов с помощью javascript?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: что-то похожее сделал Илья Кантор на learn.javascript.ru, я даже какие-то pull request ему отправлял. Конечно там все делается средствами GitHub, а на сайте всего лишь ссылка на md-исходник. наверное, он сделал что-то получше, если можно было бы.